# creating external table with partition in ATHENA results in empty table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, presto

I have an s3 location with a parquet table partitioned by a date column.

```
parquet_data ---
               --  dt=2021-07-27
                   files
               --  dt=2021-07-26
                   files
```

now I want to create an external table (CETAS)

with the table partitioned by the `dt` column.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS database.tbl_name (
  ACCOUNT_NUM                             bigint
, ID                                      bigint
, NAME                                    string
)

PARTITIONED BY (
  dt date)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://location/of/data/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'classification'='parquet',
  'typeOfData'='file'
);
```

when I select from this new table, there is no data in it at all just the headers.

is there something blaring I've missed?

things I've tried.

- re-creating the parquet table
- creating the table without partition - works, but can't see the partition and can't add the dt in table def, it comes out blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a new table with existing partitioned data, run this command:

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE database.tbl_name
```

From [MSCK REPAIR TABLE - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/msck-repair-table.html):

> The MSCK REPAIR TABLE command scans a file system such as Amazon S3 for Hive compatible partitions that were added to the file system after the table was created. MSCK REPAIR TABLE compares the partitions in the table metadata and the partitions in S3. If new partitions are present in the S3 location that you specified when you created the table, it adds those partitions to the metadata and to the Athena table.

This is required because the partitions were not created by Amazon Athena or AWS Glue, so it does not know that they exist yet.

Comment: actually the table was created by AWS Glue, but this worked, thank you!